# Are the Metal command line tools available without Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, metal

I have installed the Xcode Command Line Tools with `xcode-select --install` and they have been working fine for me. I am now trying to use Metal, and get this error:

```
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "metal", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

The macOS SDK appears to be present at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk` but I can't find a `metal` utility either there on anyway else in the tools' directory.

An [issue](https://github.com/gfx-rs/gfx/issues/2309) was filed with `gfx-rs` and put down to environment misconfiguration. It doesn't really look like this was the case, since the resolution was to point away from the Command Line Tools at the full application. An more knowledgeable [issue](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/723143/unreal-engine-inaccurately-reports-xcode-is-too-ol-1.html) was filed with Unreal Engine which implies that this is not possible with a CLI-only install.

Is it possible to use Metal without a full Xcode install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. The Metal command-line tools are located at

`$XCODE_PATH/Contents/Developer/Platforms/$PLATFORM_NAME.platform/usr/bin`

but are not in the standalone Command Line Tools download, probably because they're regarded as SDK content.

You could file an enhancement request [Radar](http://bugreport.apple.com) asking for the Metal tools to be distributed in this way; it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, gfx-rs uses the `xcrun` command to compile Metal source, as you can see in [build.rs](https://github.com/gfx-rs/gfx/blob/e7b3ede00cdaef91eff588694eac7c610fd0d136/src/backend/metal/build.rs#L49-L80). These commands are [documented by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/gpu_functions_libraries/building_a_library_with_metal_s_command_line_tools?language=objc#overview).

To compile a Metal source file into an intermediate representation (`.air`) using the `macosx` SDK:

```
$ xcrun -sdk macosx metal -c MyLibrary.metal -o MyLibrary.air
```

To link 1 or more compiled Metal IR files into a single library:

```
$ xcrun -sdk macosx metallib MyLibrary.air -o MyLibrary.metallib
```

Comment: And `xcrun` uses the current Xcode path to look up the Metal tools. Your answer doesn't apply when Xcode isn't installed.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded Xcode. Then I moved all *special* tools to CommandLineTools.
After that I threw Xcode into trash. For now everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Where do you find these special tools?