# Cannot compile simple Metal program with C++ from command line

Tags: c++, xcode, compilation, metal, clang++

I'm trying to get started making a game using Metal on a new Macbook Pro with the OS Monterey. I do not want to use xcode and will likely use a make file but FIRST I want to just compile the simplest of applications with it to test that it works.

Ive followed the steps outlined in the official docs and downloaded and unzipped the metal-cpp project into my projects root directory. My folder looks like this:

```
root
  main.cpp
  metal-cpp
    ... all the metal files here
```

My main file is simple

```cpp
#define NS_PRIVATE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define CA_PRIVATE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define MTL_PRIVATE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <Foundation/Foundation.hpp>
#include <Metal/Metal.hpp>
#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.hpp>

int main() {

}
```

Now when I try and compile this using a command like this

```bash
clang++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -g ./main.cpp -o ./main -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib
```

or

```bash
clang++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -g ./main.cpp -o ./main -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -framework Metal -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore
```

I get errors like

```
fatal error: 'Foundation/Foundation.hpp' file not found
 note: did not find header 'Foundation.hpp' in framework 'Foundation' (loaded from '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks')
```

I've also tried including a direct path like

```cpp
#include "metal-cpp/Foundation/Foundation.hpp"
#include "metal-cpp/Metal/Metal.hpp"
#include "metal-cpp/QuartzCore/QuartzCore.hpp"
```

and although it finds the headers it later fails in some deeply buried metal files that are trying to reference the framework like `<Foundation/Foundation.hpp>`

I know that these "frameworks" (not sure what that means here, sorry I'm new to C++ and compiling stuff beyond hello world) don't exist in some target location like `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks`, so I also tried

```bash
clang++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -g ./main.cpp -o ./main -I/usr/local/include -I./metal-cpp -L/usr/local/lib -L./metal-cpp -framework Metal -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore
```

but I still get the same error. I've downloaded Xcode and saw in another post ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183221/are-the-metal-command-line-tools-available-without-xcode/71008367#comment133812873_71008367:%7E:text=I%27ve%20downloaded%20Xcode.%20Then%20I%20moved%20all%20special%20tools%20to%20CommandLineTools.%20After%20that%20I%20threw%20Xcode%20into%20trash.%20For%20now%20everything%20seems%20to%20work%20fine)) that you can copy Xcode SDK packages to some frameworks directory that will make it visible when compiled, but I have no idea where to find those or if they should really be copied to `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks`.

I've spent hours on this and it seems like the only 2 ways people accomplish this is to either use Xcode or Cmake. I'm sure both of those are fine but I am a beginner and want to stick to simple command line compilation while I'm still learning, and don't want the opaque and automagic actions of Xcode builds obfuscating what's really happening, and also I like developing in VSCode, and I'm not doing cross platform builds or anything fancy so I don't want to use Cmake.

So basically what Im trying to figure out is how I include these Metal files when compiling my code!

Answer (score 0):

In one of the commands you posted, you included `-I./metal-cpp`, which is one of the things you need (assuming `metal-cpp` is in your current working directory when you compile), but you also need `-F./metal-cpp`, so that Clang++ knows where to find the additional frameworks. You shouldn't need `-L./metal-cpp`, because metal-cpp is header-only.